# How to find common sequence pattern in a column using python?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, sequence, data-analysis

I have a large dataset that looks like below:

**timestamp                                event**
2020-03-04 01:20:39                A
2020-03-04 01:21:22                  B
2020-03-04 01:21:55                  C
2020-03-04 01:22:31                  A
2020-03-04 01:23:19                  B
2020-03-04 01:24:39                  D
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
 2020-03-10 11:34:54                  C
2020-03-10 11:35:22                  A
2020-03-04 11:35:55                  B
2020-03-04 11:36:01                  D

I want to find if there are some patterns in event occurrence. For example, after event A in row 1, B occurred in row 2. {A, B} is a pattern that was repeated in row 4 and 5. I want to know if there are more patterns like this and their frequency. I am interested in sequences of max length 4(Example: C, A, B, D).

It would be really helpful if you could suggest to me any algorithm/implementation in python to do it.

Thank you!

Comment: How many rows do you have in that large dataset ? 100k ? 100M ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to concatenate the `event` column into a string then count all the patterns.

```
from collections import Counter

line = ''.join(df['event'].values)

all_patterns = Counter()
for n in range(2, 6): # pattern sizes [2, 3, 4, 5]
  all_patterns += Counter([line[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(line)-n+1)])

print (all_patterns.most_common(10)) # Top 10 most common patterns
# [('AB', 3), ('CA', 2), ('BD', 2), ('CAB', 2), ('ABD', 2), ('CABD', 2), ('BC', 1), ('DC', 1), ('ABC', 1), ('BCA', 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried PM4Py python lib? You need to convert your data to an event log following the instruction [here](https://pm4py.fit.fraunhofer.de/docs) and it will extract sequences automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can treat it as a string and your problem will turn into finding occurrence of all possible substrings in the string.

You can try the below script. It is to find occurrence of all substrings with length of 4.

```
from collection import defautdict

lstring = ''.join(df['event'].values) #convert to string
sublength = 4
substring_dict= defaultdict(int)
for i in range(len(lstring)-sublength + 1):
    substring = lstring[i:i+sublength ]
    substring_dict[substring] += 1
```